# URI constructor mistakenly encodes the "?" on mailto request when special characters are present

Tags: c#, encoding, uri, mailto

I've run into this scenario specifically with the "’" character as part of the body of the e-mail but I think it happens for other characters.

```
    string mailUrl1 = "mailto:?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It**’**s a good test\n\nFor Sure";

    var shareUri1 = new Uri(
                    mailUrl1,
                    UriKind.Absolute);
```

shareUri1.ToString():
`mailto:%3Fsubject=Testing escape characters&body=It’s a good test%0A%0AFor Sure?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It’s a good test\n\nFor Sure`

```
    string mailUrl2 = "mailto:?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It**'**s a good test\n\nFor Sure";

    var shareUri2 = new Uri(
                    mailUrl2,
                    UriKind.Absolute);
```

shareUri1.ToString():
`mailto:?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It's a good test\n\nFor Sure`

For some reason the presence of a "’" character on the first test messes up the URI parameters completely.

I was able to encode the contents of the parameters beforehand but it doesn't help as there's no way to then generate the URI object without automatically encoding again (construction with the bool parameter is deprecated). The only way I could make this work without changing the string is by not using the URI class, and working directly with strings instead.

Another weird behavior: If I fill the "mailto" part of the query, the URI is able to understand it properly. For example the following string works fine: `mailto:stackoverflow@gmail.com?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It’s a good test\n\nFor Sure`

1 - Can someone explain why this is happening?
2 - Is it possible to generate the URI object properly in this case? Maybe by configuring the encoding or something?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have special character in the body of the email.  Try encoding with : string encoded = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("body");

Comment: I tested a work-around with `UriBuilder` and found a bug. Construct a `UriBuilder` as `var builder = new UriBuilder { Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeMailto, Host = string.Empty, Path = string.Empty, Query = "subject=Testing escape characters&body=It**’**s a good test\n\nFor Sure", };`, then get the uri from the builder with `builder.ToString()`. This produces `mailto:/?subject=Testing escape characters&body=It**'**s a good test` because `UriBuilder` always puts a '/' at the beginning of the `Path` component.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately does not work. HtmlEncode does nothing to the **’** character. UrlEncode does encode it as but the question mark after the "mailto:" is still converted by the Uri

Comment: Here is list of special characters that need to be encoded : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  Any thing after the ? in the URI are parameters to the HTTP Request.  You are making the body a parameter instead of a body.  Why?

Comment: "You are making the body a parameter instead of a body" <- what do you mean by this? Is there another way of writing a "mailto" link? And I've tried encoding the character before as I mentioned, but the URI still wrongly encodes the first question mark in the URI.